# i want to decrement an attribute in node js rest api

Tags: mysql, node.js

i want to decrement an attribute on a table using mysql in node js rest api
there is my code

```
/* UPDATE EVENT nbr place */
app.put('/participate/:id', (req, res) => {


    const id = req.params.id;
    con.query('UPDATE evenement SET nbr_place = nbr_place-1 WHERE id_evenement = ?', [req.body, id], (error, result) => {
        if (error) throw error;

        res.send('decremented successfully');
    });
});
```

and im getting this error when i test it in postman

```
code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: 'UPDATE evenement SET nbr_place = nbr_place-1 WHERE id_evenement = '
```

Any help please?

Comment: I suspect that `[req.body, id]` should be just `[id]`.

Comment: OK let me post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
con.query(
    'UPDATE evenement SET nbr_place = nbr_place-1 WHERE id_evenement = ?', 
    [req.body, id], 
    (error, result) 
=> {
```

The problem is that you are passing two parameters while your query actually expects just one.

`[req.body, id]` should be just `[id]`:

```
con.query(
    'UPDATE evenement SET nbr_place = nbr_place-1 WHERE id_evenement = ?', 
    [id], 
    (error, result) 
=> {
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're passing, `req.body` as a placeholder, and you should only send `id`. Change `[req.body, id]` to `[id]`

```
 con.query(
   'UPDATE evenement SET nbr_place = nbr_place-1 WHERE id_evenement = ?', 
   [id], // Only pass ID
   (error, result) => {

   }
 )
```